# iam not able to post data on facebook using share intent code

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

```
 private void shareonfb(){
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content to share");
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
        for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
            if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                startActivity(shareIntent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

the data cannot be post it comes empty when i try the Extra text to post on fb

Comment: Sharing via intent is now not supporting by FB, please look at new library provided by facebook.

Comment: i tried it by facebook ShareLinkContent but iam able to post link only

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prefill a user message as that's against Facebook's Platform Policies. Any message you try to add will be stripped out by the app.

https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control